# How to scheduler call function when something change in database Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-scheduler

I'm setting up a new application when something changes in the database; I need to call a function in my background or backend, that function returns some id and data from the database.

Maybe someone can help me write a good cron job.

Laravel scheduler call function when something changes in the database.

Comment: Are you using eloquent models?  Have you looked into using something like the `updated` event hook?

Comment: Have you considered an Event Listener? https://laravel.com/docs/master/events